# How to filter data from multiple pages of same html table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the below script fo search data from the table, This works fine when the searched data is on the same page, but when data is on page 2 and I am searching on page 1 it will not display any results. I am displaying 25 rows of table each page because it can have 1000's of rows. Now I am on page 2 (rows 26-50) and I search for something that is on page 1 then it will not return any results.

```
<div align="center">  
<input type="text" name="search" id="myInput" class="form-control" onkeyup="searchTable()"/>  
</div>  
//Pagination Code
$results_per_page = 25;
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);
if (!isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = 1;
}else{
$page = $_GET['page'];
}
$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM programteamtable LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sqlget);
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>";
echo $row['dispID'];
//More Columns
}

<script>
function searchTable() {
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("programteamtable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the line `table = document.getElementById("programteamtable");` must be retrieving only the rows in the current page. You should be searching against the original data set before paginating. Otherwise you should specify what means you are using to do the pagination.

Comment: Just added pagination code

Comment: By using mysql based pagination you cant search the entire list using javascript.
It's either you change your search script to search from the database or you retrieve all values from database do the pagination using javascript.
But why re-invent the wheel?
Why don't you just use Data Tables?

Comment: because I don't know how to connect search box and database tables, any article for reference?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

This can help

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot. Had no idea about datatables. That's exactly what I wanted.